# ¿Porque este codigo entra en bucle infinito?

Tags: c++

Buenas, estoy aprendiendo a programar en C++. Estoy escribiendo un programa para practicar y no se porque entra en bucle infinito. He intentado limpiar el buffer de cin pero no da resultado.

```
  while(state){
    cout<<opciones<<endl;
    cin>>opcion;
    cout<<opcion<<endl;
    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            cout<<"funcionoo"<<endl;
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        case 4:
            state=0;
            break;
        default:
            string sep2(anchodepantalla,'*');
            cout<<"Opcion no valida. Intentelo de nuevo."<<endl;
            cout<<sep2<<endl;
            break;
    }
    opcion=0;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Como es la salida cuando queda en bucle?

Comment: Imprime lo que hay dentro de la variable opciones que esta definida como: string opciones = "1) Ver tareas\n2) Agregar nueva tarea\n3) Eliminar tareas\n4) Salir";

Comment: El codigo sale del bucle cuando ingresas "4" por la entrada. ¿No es ese el comportamiento deseado?

Comment: No explique bien, disculpas. El codigo entra en bucle infinito cuando oprimo una letra. El comportamiento que esperaba era que se fuera por la opcion default.

Comment: has intentado con otro ciclo podria ser un do while tal vez

Comment: Puedes hacer que "opción" sea una variable de tipo char y asi validas el ingreso de letras te dejo un ejemplo: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/6463/ ¿Te serviria?

Comment: Si, esa podria ser una solución. Pero me queda la duda de porque entra en bucle infinito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `while` `std::cin` esta esperando un `int` si usted no le pasa algo correcto para meterlo dentro del `int` falla:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int state = 1;
    int opcion = 0;

    while(state){
    //cout<<opciones<<endl;

    //cin espera un int comprueba que es un entero;
    if (cin >> opcion) {

    } else {

      //buscamos el default
      opcion = 0;
    }
    //cout<<opcion<<endl;
    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            cout<<"funcionoo"<<endl;
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        case 4:
            state=0;
            break;
        default:

            cout<<"Opcion no valida. Intentelo de nuevo."<<endl;

            break;
    }

    //cin.ignore();
}
    return 0;
}
```

creo que esto funciona como espera, cuente con que parte del codigo me lo he imaginado.

Comment: @Andres V. esto es lo que buscaba, le funciona como usted esperaba?. Saludos

Comment: Ahora me cierra. Error conceptual el mio. Gracias

Comment: @Andres V. cuando dices ahora me cierra te refieres a que ahora te funciona bien?. Saludos

Comment: Exactamente, modismo argentino jaja. Saludos